# How to select mysql rows where condition is stored in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which stores states of user search. It looks like this:

```
id | user_id | option | condition | value
------------------------------------------
 4 |       2 | price  | >=        | 300000
 5 |       2 | price  | <=        | 900000
 6 |       4 | status | =         | 1     
 7 |       4 | type   | =         | 1     
 8 |       5 | price  | >=        | 100000
 9 |       5 | price  | <=        | 125000
10 |       5 | status | =         | 2     
11 |       5 | type   | >=        | 2     
13 |       6 | price  | >=        | 200000
14 |       7 | price  | >=        | 500000
18 |       8 | price  | <=        | 600000
------------------------------------------
```

Now, I need to get all `user_id` where `price` value of `400000` fits any condition range (per user), OR `status` matches `1`.

So, for this query, the result should be `2,4,6,8`.

Any suggestions are welcome!

UPD: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea73a4/1

Comment: You may want to change the table schema to have columns like `price_min, price_max`. For one-sided ranges, you can put very large positive and negative bounds.

Comment: Thank you for advice. Yes, it may work, but I'm worried about large amount of options. Now there are about 20 options could be stored. And they may grow in further.

Comment: Post up an sqlfiddle

Comment: Updated post with the link.

Answer (score 0):

Try following;)

```
select distinct s.`user_id`
from `search_state` s
inner join (
    select `option`, `user_id`, max(`value` + 0) as maxV, min(`value` + 0) as minV, group_concat(`condition`) as `condition`
    from `search_state` 
    where `user_id` = `user_id`
    and `option` = `option`
    and `option` = 'price'
    group by `option`, `user_id`
) t on s.`option` = 'status' and s.`value` = '1'
or (
    s.`option` = 'price' and (
        s.`user_id` = t.`user_id`
        and s.`option` = t.`option` and
        case 
            when t.maxV = t.minV and find_in_set(',', t.`condition`) <> 0
                then 400000 = t.`maxV`
            when t.maxV = t.minV and find_in_set(',', t.`condition`) = 0 and t.`condition` = '>='
                then 400000 >= t.maxV
            when t.maxV = t.minV and find_in_set(',', t.`condition`) = 0 and t.`condition` = '<='
                then 400000 <= t.maxV
            when t.maxV <> t.minV then (400000 >= t.minV and 400000 <= t.maxV)
         end
    )
)
```

[**SQLFiddle DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea73a4/25)